# Could not find member 'init' in a Dictionary extension

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, extension-methods

I found the following code snippet in [this](https://github.com/udacity/ios-networking/blob/step-4.11-init-task-for-post/TheMovieManager/TheMovieManager/TMDBClient.swift#L195) sample project. It takes a `[String: AnyObject]` dictionary, escapes the spacial characters and creates a parametrized string.

```
class func escapedParameters(parameters: [String : AnyObject]) -> String {
    var urlVars = [String]()

    for (key, value) in parameters {
        let stringValue = "\(value)"
        let escapedValue = stringValue.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

        urlVars += [key + "=" + "\(escapedValue!)"]
    }
    return (!urlVars.isEmpty ? "?" : "") + join("&", urlVars)
}
```

The original code is a class function. I wanted to make this an extension method of the Dictionary type.

```
extension Dictionary {

    func escapedParameters() -> String {
        var urlVars = [String]()

        for (key, value) in self {
            let stringValue = "\(value)"
            let escapedValue = stringValue.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

            urlVars += [key + "=" + "\(escapedValue!)"]
        }
        return (!urlVars.isEmpty ? "?" : "") + join("&", urlVars)
    }

}
```

But I get the following error at this line `urlVars += [key + "=" + "\(escapedValue!)"]`.

**Could not find member 'init'**

I can't figure out why or how to correct this. This issue doesn't occur when it's a class function.

Comment: you can`t += to arrays.

Comment: @luk2302 you can't use += to append a single item but you can use it to append one array to another. That includes a single element array

Comment: @LeoDabus ahhh, i see what he is trying to do there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
urlVars.append("\(key)=\(escapedValue!)")
```